# Diff Eq: Find the general solution of $y'= y^2 -1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y' = y ^ 2 -1$$

> I supposed that this can be separated, first solve the homogeneous equation, and then the particular solution. 
>   But I don't know how to proceed when I get the homogeneous one.

The homogeneous sol. is:

$$\frac{-1}{x+c} = y,$$

$c$ constant.

> Then, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using separation of variables, we have $dy / (y^2 - 1) = dx$. Using the partial fraction decomposition,
$$
\frac{-1/2\ dy}{y+1} + \frac{1/2 \ dy}{y-1} = dx
$$

and thus

$$
-1/2\log(y+1) + 1/2\log(y-1) = x + C
$$
or (keeping the same name $C$ for various arbitrary constants)

$$
\log\bigg(\bigg|\frac{y-1}{y+1}\bigg|\bigg) = 2x + C,
$$

$$
\frac{y-1}{y+1} = C\exp(2x),
$$
$$
y-1 = C\exp(2x)y + C\exp(2x), 
$$

and finally
$$
y = \frac{C\exp(2x) + 1}{1-C\exp(2x)}.
$$

Edit: oops, there's one more solution, the constant function $y = -1$. We threw it away when we divided by $y^2 - 1$ in the first step!

Answer (score 3):

If it's separable, you don't need to bother with the homogeneous equation. Just solve

$$\int \frac{1}{y^2 - 1} dy = \int 1 dx$$

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted, it is correct